# JSON call returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am relatively new to using JSON and have run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve. I have set up a generic handler (detailed below), and also a page with a JSON call to get the response from the handler and render it.

The page with the JSON call is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        triggerCall();

        function triggerCall() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                type: 'POST',
                headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
            });

            $.ajax
              (
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Services/DepartmentListHandler.ashx",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.msg);
                        displayDirectory(data.msg);
                    },
                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
                    }
                }
              );
        }

        function displayDirectory(dirlist) {
            var tablestring = '<table class="centered-table"><tr><td colspan="2">';
            tablestring = tablestring + "<tr><td><u>DeptCode</u></td><td><u>HeaderText</u></td></tr>";

            for (var i = 0, len = dirlist.length; i < len; ++i) {
                tablestring = tablestring + "<tr>";
                tablestring = tablestring + "   <td>" + dirlist[i].DeptCode + "</td>";
                tablestring = tablestring + "   <td>" + dirlist[i].HeaderText + "</td>";
                tablestring = tablestring + "</tr>";
            }

            tablestring = tablestring + "</table>";
            $('#divDirectoryList').html(tablestring);
        }

    });

    </script>


<div id="divDirectoryList"></div>
```

And the handler method is:

```
Public Class DepartmentListHandler
Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim json = New JavaScriptSerializer()

    Dim lst As New List(Of DepartmentList)

    Dim cls1 As New DepartmentList(1, 0, "DEP1", "Header", 1, True, False)
    lst.Add(cls1)

    Dim serialisedList As String = json.Serialize(lst)

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
    context.Response.Write(serialisedList)
End Sub

ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

All the seems to happen is that the alert in the 'success' branch returns 'undefined' each time, and the table is not rendered at all.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post the generated JSON instead of the code generating the JSON

Comment: Can you post a sample of the generated JSON instead of the .net code that's generating the JSON.

Comment: can you please use the `console.log(data)` to check what is coming from `Handler`

Comment: Put `console.dir(data);` inside the success function (instead of the ugly alert) and check the console to see what the data object is.

Comment: Thanks for replying! LOG: [object Object] is what's appearing in the log

Comment: now try to use `console.log(data[0]);`

Comment: Still appears as LOG: [object Object]. If I add .msg after it, it logs as 'undefined'

Comment: @Mark: what is the o/p of console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: It's coming up with: LOG: [{"Id":1,"Parent":0,"DeptCode":"DEP1","HeaderText":"Header","Order":1,"Display":true,"Header":false}]

Comment: OK folks, I've no idea what I did before - but changing the 'success' condition to "displayDirectory(data);" worked this time. I can only assume I didn't serialise it properly in the handler. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the json data that you are serializing in our code is incorrectly formatted. json data to show as "data.msg" must be received as

```
{
    msg: 'some message',
    data:'some data'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually on client side you will get  [object Object] collection of object ,that object contain the your list of objects.

Print 
console.log('data',data); and see in the fire fox.

**you can simply get as**

```
data[0].msg;
data[0].id;
```

or you can iterate the java script object with jquery then get as below

```
data.msg;
data.id
```